# specify log request format in aiohttp 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, aiohttp

I'm using aiohttp 2 with Python 3.6 and want to log the requests coming to the application.

I did:

```
# use ISO timestamps
from time import gmtime
logging.Formatter.converter = gmtime
# create a formatter
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s - %(message)s', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
ch.setFormatter(formatter)

# show all emssages (default is WARNING)
logging.getLogger('aiohttp.access').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# attach the handler
logging.getLogger('aiohttp.access').addHandler(ch)
```

and now when the application is running I get a log in this format:

```
2017-04-19T16:02:17 INFO aiohttp.access - 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Apr/2017:16:02:17 +0000] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 404 547 "-" "curl/7.51.0"
```

the `message` component has a redundant timestamp, and I'd like to customize its format. The [documentation](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/logging.html) says it should be possible but I don't understand how to make it actually work and there are no code examples.

I found only [this usage](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp-devtools/blob/bf97ba10b2b2b889c04fc30e0299aa158a383dec/aiohttp_devtools/runserver/serve.py#L83) but with:

```
mylogger = logging.Logger('aiohttp.access')
mylogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
mylogger.addHandler(ch)

handler = app.make_handler(
        logger=mylogger,
        access_log_format='%r %s %b',
)
```

the application produces no log at all. I don't understand what `make_handler` does exactly, and a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39956400/aiohttp-how-to-log-access-log) doesn't help.

How can I format the `message` part of the log and insert the elements listed in the aiohttp docs ?

Comment: Did you call `aiohttp.web.Application.make_handler()` ?

Comment: No, in that example they call it on the app instance. I tried nonetheless and it says `make_handler() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'` so it seems it's an instance method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see my sample:

```
import asyncio
import logging

from aiohttp import web


mylogger = logging.getLogger('aiohttp.access')
mylogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
mylogger.addHandler(ch)


async def handle(request):
    name = request.match_info.get('name', "Anonymous")
    text = "Hello, " + name
    return web.Response(text=text)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

app = web.Application(loop=loop)
app.router.add_get('/', handle)
app.router.add_get('/{name}', handle)

loop.run_until_complete(
    loop.create_server(
        app.make_handler(access_log=mylogger,
                         access_log_format='%r %s %b'), '0.0.0.0', 8080))
loop.run_forever()
loop.close()
```

run it and access 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/xmwd', you will see `GET /xmwd HTTP/1.1 200 11` in your console.