# logging http requests from aiohttp

Tags: python, logging, aiohttp

I would like to log all HTTP requests sent by an [aiohttp](http://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/index.html) `ClientSession`. The docs provide a list of available [loggers](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/logging.html). So I tried the following:

```
import asyncio
import logging

import aiohttp

logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
http_logger = logging.getLogger("aiohttp.client")
http_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
http_logger.propagate = True


async def make_request():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get('https://httpbin.org/get') as resp:
            return await resp.text()


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
response_text = loop.run_until_complete(make_request())

print(response_text)
```

But this only produced the following output:

```
DEBUG:asyncio:Using selector: EpollSelector
// response text print here
```

I tried all the loggers from that list in the docs and then searched for questions. This one is similar: [specify log request format in aiohttp 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43500983/specify-log-request-format-in-aiohttp-2)

The answer describes how to set up logging for an aiohttp server. Interestingly, they have to explicitly register the logger:

```
app = web.Application(loop=loop)
app.router.add_get('/', handle)
app.router.add_get('/{name}', handle)

loop.run_until_complete(
    loop.create_server(
        app.make_handler(access_log=mylogger,   #<--------------- HERE
                         access_log_format='%r %s %b'), '0.0.0.0', 8080))
```

Is this necessary for the client, too?
The only way where I could reasonably inject my logger would probably be the session. But the [API reference](http://%20http://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#aiohttp.ClientSession) for the ClientSession doesn't specify any logger argument.

Comment: MB the best solution is manually log all required data. You can do this using ClientTracing features (https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html#client-tracing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Client request-response lifecycle is pretty complex, that's why aiohttp doesn't log it.

Please use [client tracing](http://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html#client-tracing) to register callbacks for all steps. After that, you can log all events by any convenient method (print, logging, whatever).

Comment: yes that works. But I don't understand why they explicitly list an 'aiohttp.client' logger. That should be for logging client-side requests, right ? There should be a way to get this logger to work

Comment: Right now aiohttp uses `aiohttp.client` only for reporting warnings about client API usage.

Answer (score 5):

All that was necessary for me was to import logging and add

```
 logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
```

in my make_app().

The default access.log format is quite wordy so I calmed it down a bit with the access_log_format argument to web.run_app

```
web.run_app(app, access_log_format=" :: %r %s %T %t")
```